# How to convert Configslurper config to Log4j?

Tags: java, groovy, log4j

The Groovy ConfigSlurper http://groovy.codehaus.org/ConfigSlurper gives an nice example on how to define Log4j configuration using the ConfigSlurper.

E.g.

```
log4j {
    appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
    appender."stdout.layout"="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    rootLogger="error,stdout"
    logger {
        org.springframework="info,stdout"
    }
    additivity {
        org.springframework=false
    }
}
```

Basically the ConfigSlurper just gives back a nested map with Java types like String, Boolean etc.

What is the best way to actually use these config settings and apply them to the underlying Log4j system?

Note: I'm not using Grails, but vanilla Spring.

Comment: Not sure, but does: `PropertyConfigurator.configure( new ConfigSlurper().parse( new File('config.groovy').toURL() ).toProperties() )` work?

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim Yates commented:

```
org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(
    new ConfigSlurper().parse(new File("config.groovy").toURL()).toProperties())
```

works brilliantly!

Thanks Tim!

Answer (score 0):

You can config log4j directly from code without the need to create a properties files like this:

```
def log4jConfig = """
log4j {
    appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
    appender."stdout.layout"="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    rootLogger="error,stdout"
    logger {
        org.springframework="info,stdout"
    }
    additivity {
        org.springframework=false
    }
}
"""

def config = new ConfigSlurper().parse(log4jConfig)
PropertyConfigurator.configure(config.toProperties())
```